# Followng PHP function not working properly

Tags: php

The following function is to display m
error messages. but it does not display the error messeege?

```
<?php
public function displayErrors() {
        $html = '<ul class="bg-danger">';
        foreach ($this->_errors as $error) {
            $html .= '<li>' . $error[0] . '</li>';
            $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery("document").ready(function(){jQuery("#'.$error[1].'").parent().closest("div").addClass("has-error")});</script>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        return $html;
}
```

Comment: Maybe there simply were no errors? Maybe you did not actually call the function anywhere? Impossible for us to tell, with just what you have shown so far. Please go read [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Why do you inject javascript into it? and whats your error array looks like and how do you / where do you call your displayErrors() function

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

assuming your class is like this

```
class yourErrorsClass {

    public $_errors = [];

    public function __construct($errors=[]){
        $this->_errors=$errors;
    }

    public function displayErrors() {
        $html = '<ul class="bg-danger">';
        foreach ($this->_errors as $error) {
            $html .= '<li>' . $error[0] . '</li>';
            $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery("document").ready(function(){jQuery("#' . $error[1] . '").parent().closest("div").addClass("has-error")});</script>';
        }
        $html .= '</ul>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

this is how you push your messages

```
$messages=new yourErrorsClass([['username failed','username'],['invalid email id','emailid']]);
```

this is how you print

```
echo $messages->displayErrors();
```